# Java WireMock- How to edit an existent stub

Tags: java, testing, wiremock

I'm looking for a way to programmatically edit a stub that is already registered.

I feel like I have most of the components, just not sure how to get it to fit together.

For example:

```java
WireMockServer server;//assume set up, read in mappings from json, and running

@Test
public void test(){
    StubMapping mapping = this.server.getStubMapping(--);
    
    // Just this doesn't work
    mapping.getResponse().getJsonBody()
        .set("someValue", TextNode.valueOf("newValue"));
    
    //Noticed this exists, but unsure how to get a StubBuilder from an existant mapping
    this.server.editStub(StubBuilder);
    
    //Noticed this also exists, but no change in resulting response, similar to original issue
    this.server.editStubMapping(mapping);
    

    //do test...
}
```

Any ideas? I am sure I am close, just missing some connecting piece. I was hoping the mapping returned was by reference, and not by value which it seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to make it work:

```java
public void test(){
    StubMapping mapping = this.server.getStubMapping(--);
    ResponseDefinition response = mapping.getResponse();
    
    ObjectNode body = (ObjectNode)response.getJsonBody();
    body.set("someValue", TextNode.valueOf("newValue"));

    mapping.setResponse(like(response).withJsonBody(body).build());

    //rest of test
}
```